# Are file names in Ubuntu case sensitive?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, case-sensitive

I mean in windows if create a file named “a.txt” and trying to create another file in the same destination as “A.txt” is prohibited.

Is it same in Ubuntu?

Thank you for paying your valuable attention for a silly question.

Comment: Just try it. Also, this question is off-topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To your title: Yes they are case-sensitive.

To your inline question: No, there is nothing that would prevent you from doing that.

Unix & Linux typically use case-sensitive filesystems, so there is a distinct difference between `A.txt` and `a.txt`.

Answer (score 4):

yes in ubuntu file names are case sensitive and you can create two files with caps and small :)

So A.txt is valid on same location with a.txt.

:)